# Default value for DateTime parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a parameter called 'FromMonth' which is populated with values from a dataset as:

```
DisplayValue        KeyValue  
2015, September     2015-09-01
2015, October       2015-10-01
```

The `KeyValue` is a datetime value which I need to pass to report dataset parameter. This parameter can have null values.

I have set the parameter type to `DateTime` along with these settings:

```
Allow null value = `true`
Default Value - Specify values - `null`
```

When the parameter is displayed in report preview, it is having default value as

```
<Select a value>
```

If I don't select it and click *View Report*, it prompts me with this message:

> Please select a value for parameter 'From Month'

Why user is forced to select a value, if I have selected **Allow null value** = `true`?

Second issue is-
I want to display `All` instead of `Select a value`
Do I need to change the underlying stored procedure to include this row?

Thank you!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are telling the parameter to allow "(NULL)" but that isn't a possible value in your dropdown list of acceptable values.  Edit your dataset query to allow a null value or append a union to the bottom of the query like:

```
UNION 
SELECT 'NULL' as DisplayValue, NULL as KeyValue
```

That will allow "Null" to be a selectable value and it will then become the default.